# How can I use parameterize method within an anchor tag as an href attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on a ruby on rails project and I am using a variable to dynamically inject a string as part of an href within a html.erb file.

```
a class= "hyphen-anchor" href="#<%=add_hyphen_to_string string%>"
```

The `add_hyphen_to_string` method is a helper function that I wrote that returns a string with blanks replace with hyphens

"how are you" become "how-are-you"

I am attempting to replace the helper function with the parameterize method instead but can't get the syntax right as it does not produce a link.  I've tried

```
a class= "hyphen-anchor" href="#<%=string.parameterize%>"
```

any help would be great.

Comment: You're handcrafting that link instead of using `link_to`?

Comment: the link is part of a generated pdf.  I was following along to the syntax on DocRaptor documentation. (https://docraptor.com/documentation/style#pdf-links)

Comment: "it does not produce a link" -> what does it produce? What does the HTML look like in a browser?

Comment: it does not produce a link.  The html still produces the p tag

Comment: Does this work `<%= link_to 'My Link', '#' + string.parameterize, class: 'hypen-anchor' %>` ?